# Get available TTS languages

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

How can I get a list of all the available English TTS languages and all the available Spanish TTS languages? What I'd like to do is allow the user to choose which English voice and which Spanish voice to use.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution. I hope this helps anyone with a similar problem.

```
Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
List<Locale> localeListEnglish = new ArrayList<Locale>();
List<Locale> localeListSpanish = new ArrayList<Locale>();
for (Locale locale : locales)
{
    if (tts.isLanguageAvailable(locale) == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
    {
        if (locale.getLanguage().equals("en"))
            localeListEnglish.add(locale);
        else if (locale.getLanguage().equals("es"))
            localeListSpanish.add(locale);
    }
}
String message = new String("");
for (int i = 0; i < localeListEnglish.size(); i++)
    message += localeListEnglish.get(i) + "\n";
for (int i = 0; i < localeListSpanish.size(); i++)
    message += localeListSpanish.get(i) + "\n";
Log.i("debug", message);
```